# No Hash entry in Release file

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I am new to Ubuntu and this is 2nd day of me struggling with this system/problem, including damaging my Ubuntu installation and having to start over, so I really hope someone can provide a working solution.
I installed Ubuntu only because I need to use it with Nvidia CUDA Toolkit 7.5 from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
After I download it and follow instructions, 'sudo apt-get update' gives me such error message:

```
W: file:///var/cuda-repo-7-5-local/Release.gpg: Signature by key 889BEE522DA690103C4B085ED88C3D385C37D3BE uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-7-5-local/Release  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_var_cuda-repo-7-5-local_Release which is considered strong enough for security purposes
```

I tried both solutions from [How can I force 16.04 to add a repository even if it isn't considered secure enough?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760242/how-can-i-force-16-04-to-add-a-repository-even-if-it-isnt-considered-secure-eno) and nonoe of them worked, but I am not permitted to post comments there.

The first solution suggesting to download 'cuda_7.5.18_linux.run' failed miserably and destroyed my Ubuntu, as the driver couldn't be installed without stopping X server and blacklisting Nouveau (for which I also had to fish for instructions on Google). After finally seemingly 'successfully' installing the Nvidia driver, Ubuntu went into endless login loop ([Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)) and I had to reinstall it.

The 2nd suggested solution to alter "/var/cuda-repo-7-5-local/Release" also didn't work as the SHA256 posted there seems to be wrong.
I'd greatly appreciate a working solution before I run out of monitors I'm throwing at the wall.

Comment: I have the same error. Any progress?